# Having hard problems understanding when to integrate and when to use reciprocal identities

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

For example lets take this integral $∫\sin x \ dx$ the answer will be $-\cos x + C$ but if we take $∫\csc x \sin x \ dx$ the answer will be $1/\sin x \sin x \ dx \to x + C$ here why we used reciprocal identity $1/\sin x$ instead of integrating $\csc x$ and $\sin x$ respectively like this $-\ln|\csc x+\cot x|-\cos x + C$ are we supposed to use reciprocals for simplifying? same goes for $∫\sin x \ dx$ why didn't we say the answer is $1/\csc x + C$ instead of $-\cos x + C$.

Comment: $-\cos(x) + C = - \frac{1}{\text{sec}(x)} + C.$  Personally, I try to find the easiest solution (i.e. expression) possible, when attacking a problem.  If the problem (for example) does not involve reciprocals, then my first try will be to solve the problem without any reciprocals.

Comment: We cannot "integrate $\csc x$ and $\sin x$ respectively" since $\csc x \sin x \ne \csc x + \sin x$. Besides, we cannot integrate the factors of a product respectively in general.